# What is the correct Doctrin's column type for MySql's YEAR type

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I want to map a property from one of my doctrine's entity to a table's column with [datatype of YEAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/year.html).

At the moment I'm using the [doctrine's integer type](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#integer-types) with the length of 4 as demonstrated bellow, but I was wondering if there is a better match for such mapping.

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="year", type="integer", length=4, nullable=true)
 */
private $year;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any exact numeric type should be ok

Comment: yeah, thats what I'm doing but was wondering if doctrine has any more specific type for it.

Comment: According to the MySQL documentation, `YEAR` is a one byte type.  So you could get away with `smallint`, which is 2 bytes, or any other numeric type (which is larger than `smallint`).

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, I did go with your suggestion about smallint in your answer. I guess it would be fair if we accept Aron's answer. p.s. if the question helped to find out about the MySql datatype, you might want to consider spend some of your votes on it ;)